# How/when is くる used to mean difficult/unpleasant?

Tags: slang

In [this video](https://youtu.be/61HwQxYuYoM?t=1m51s), a Japanese YouTuber says the following:

> 美味しいですけど、ご飯の同じ量と卵の同じ量って、ちょっと卵のほうが**きます**ね。でも美味しいです。

It seems like きます means むずかしい here.

Some other examples:

> (辛い食べ物を食べた後に)これは後から**くる**！

Apparently this implies that the effects of the spicy food kicked in only after eating it (it seemed okay at the time).

> 朝からAC/DCは**きます**ね。

The speaker here doesn't like listening to loud rock music in the morning.

Are these common usages of くる? I haven't found anything in my usual dictionaries about it. Does anyone know how the usage arose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ちょっと卵のほうがきますね

Yes this 来る is a verb that means "(feels) tough/heavy" or something like that.

> (辛い食べ物を食べた後に)これは後からくる！

Just as you guessed. The spicy stimulus "comes" to the nervous system a few moments after eating it.

> 朝からAC/DCはきますね。

This one is context-dependent, but くる here vaguely refers to something positive and exciting. "～ rocks" is the closest word I know, but there may be a better translation.

And don't forget くる can also mean "in" or "hot" in the music industry:

> 今週は○○がきている.
>   ○○ is hot this week.

---

In all the situations above, くる is often written as クる (or キて, etc.) to [emphasize the slangy usage](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/6520/5010).

Comment: Thanks. クる is too versatile for its own good :) I'd still be interested to know how each of the usages arose - the connection to 'come' seems tenuous at best for a few of them.

Answer (score 4):

In the examples you gave it just literally means "come". Imagine sound coming to your ears or flavor coming to your mouth. This is how it is being used in the examples you gave. It is a common idiomatic use of the work くる in Japanese. She means that with the same amount of rice or egg, the egg feels heavier as she eats it. It does not necessarily mean 難しい or imply dislike on the part of the speaker.

Answer (score 2):

This usage of くる goes as follow.

A Dictionary says

> 何かによって、ある反応・感覚・感情が起こる。「ぴんとくる」「胸にじんとくる温かい言葉」

It is translated as "Someone has a reaction, emotion, and feeling by something."

Whether what reaction someone have is according to the context.