# What does こっちが mean?

Tags: grammar, meaning, translation, sentence, anime

I am trying to figure out what ''こっちがキレるわよ'' means

This is the sentence it came from:

A:「なんですって！　起こしにきてあげたのに逆ギレ？　こっちがキレるわよ！」

For context, A is trying to wake B up:

> B: 「にぁああああああ！　怪我すると思うなら！　やめさせてくださぃぃぃ！！」
> A: 「だめよ……やめたら、また寝ちゃうでしょ。昔からあなたの行動は進化ないものっ」
> B: 「寝ない！　もう寝ない所存！　頼みますから！！　フトンの上で正座しないでぇ！」
> A: 「だめよ！　口でいくら言っても、ちゃんと起きないと信じられないからねっ」
> B: 「あんたバカかっ！」
> A: 「なんですって！　起こしにきてあげたのに逆ギレ？　こっちがキレるわよ！」

Comment: Possible duplicate/related: [Using こっち to replace 私](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/74371/using-%e3%81%93%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a1-to-replace-%e7%a7%81); [こっち、そっち、あっち、どっち](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/21184/%e3%81%93%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a1-%e3%81%9d%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a1-%e3%81%82%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a1-%e3%81%a9%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slang キレる means "to be mad", or "to get pissed", while 逆ギレ would quite literally mean "to be angry back at someone who should normally be the one angry", where the person at fault is the one being angry.

The こっち part would mean "here", it implies "me" or "I". The が after is simply pointing towards "who" specifically it is that should be angry.

You might also be familiar with the expression:「それはこっちのセリフ！」"That's my line!". The こっち serves the exact same function here.

So, to put it back in context, the sentence would read:

A:「なんですって！起こしにきてあげたのに逆ギレ？こっちがキレるわよ！」

A: "What did you just say!? I came to wake you up and now you're mad at me? I should be the one angry!" (A is pissed at B for not being grateful)

To learn more about where キレる came from, read this post too: [Where does the word キレる come from?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6519/where-does-the-word-%E3%82%AD%E3%83%AC%E3%82%8B-come-from)